# How add filters on Set[(String, String)] Set[Tuple] with two element

Tags: scala, tuples

I am new to scala. I'm trying to apply a filter on Set[(String, String)]. The filter is to remove duplicates even if it is case sensitive.

```
Input: Tuple 1 ("Low", "Low")
       Tuple 2 ("medium", "medium")
       Tuple 3 ("High", "High")
       Tuple 4 ("Medium", "Medium")
       Tuple 5 ("low", "low")

Output: Tuple 1 ("Low", "Low")
        Tuple 2 ("High", "High")
        Tuple 3 ("medium", "medium")
```

So if the string is Low and low then filter should give Low(or whichever comes first) I tried to apply groupBy. So how can this be achieved?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One handy tool, made available in Scala 2.13.x, is `distinctBy()`. Unfortunately it's not available on a `Set`, I guess because sets are assumed to be distinct by definition.

```
input.toList
     .distinctBy{case (a,b) => (a.toUpperCase,b.toUpperCase)}
     .toSet
//res0: Set[(String, String)] = Set((Medium,Medium), (High,High), (low,low))
```

Note that a `Set`, by definition, has no order so "whichever comes first" is actually meaningless.

---

**pre-2.13.x**

If you are willing to settle on a standard presentation format then you can do this.

```
input.map{case (a,b) => (a.capitalize,b.capitalize)}

//res0: Set[(String, String)] = Set((Low,Low), (High,High), (Medium,Medium))
```

Comment: I am not using 2.13.x. The version I'm using doesn't have distinctBy on List

Answer (score 0):

```
val setOfPairs: Set[(String, String)] =
    Set(("Low", "Low"), ("medium", "medium"), ("High", "High"), ("Medium", "Medium"), ("low", "low"))

setOfPairs.foldLeft(Set.empty[(String, String)]) { (acc, pair) =>
    if (acc
          .map { case (left, right) => (left.capitalize, right.capitalize) }
          .contains((pair._1.capitalize, pair._2.capitalize))) acc
    else acc + pair
  }
```

This should give you whichever set pair comes first.

Comment: But a `Set` has no order so there is no consistent "first".

Answer (score 0):

If you not using scala 2.13.x, you can do it as follows:

You can use this not so efficient method (no consistent)

```
Set(
  "Low" -> "Low",
  "medium" -> "medium",
  "High" -> "High",
  "low" -> "low")
  .map { case tuple @ (key,value) => key.toUpperCase -> tuple }
  .toMap
  .values
  .toSet
```

Outputs:
`Set((low,low), (medium,medium), (High,High))`

Or:

```
Set(
  "Low" -> "Low",
  "medium" -> "medium",
  "High" -> "High",
  "low" -> "low")
  .foldLeft((Seq.empty[String], Set.empty[(String,String)])) { case (seed @ (keys, set), tuple @ (key, _)) => {
    val currKey = key.toUpperCase
    if (keys.contains(currKey)) seed else (currKey +: keys, set + tuple)
    }
  }._2
```

Outputs: `Set((Low,Low), (medium,medium), (High,High))`

**Note:** For efficient, you can Using instead of Set.empty, some sort of iterable collection which not checks for duplication, and then in ._2 transform it to set

```
List(
  "Low" -> "Low",
  "medium" -> "medium",
  "High" -> "High",
  "low" -> "low",
  "high" -> "high")
  .foldLeft((Seq.empty[String], Seq.empty[(String,String)])) { case (seed @ (keys, seq), tuple @ (key, _)) => {
    val currKey = key.toUpperCase
    if (keys.contains(currKey)) seed else (currKey +: keys, tuple +: seq)
  }
  }._2.toSet
```

(consistent)